# Как подключить jdb дебаггер к удалённому приложению, чтобы видеть исходники?

Tags: java

Как с помощью jdb подключить дебаггер к удалённому приложению на сервере, чтобы иметь возможность чтения исходников?

Comment: Во-первых, удалённое приложение должно быть скомпилировано с отладочными символами. Во-вторых, исходный код должен быть на локальной машине.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Ситуация такая, что проект огромный, собирался в jar мавеном, и с помощью spring tool suit 3 есть возможность подключиться. Думал по аналогии можно так же сделать и в jdb

Comment: Все отладчики используются Java Debug Interface. Так что Spring Tool Suite нужно то же самое, что и jdb - отладочные символы и доступ к исходникам.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, тогда допустим я словил `breakpoint`, пишу `list`, и получаю `Source file not found: file.java`. Есть возможность указать на него?

Comment: Я попробовал use, и с примитивным hello world получилось

Comment: Ключ [-sourcepath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html#CHDBCFAA) используйте.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто правильно скомпилировал(с флагов `-g`) и смогли подключить удаленную отладку, но не видно исходников:
В *cli* `jdb` есть команда `use`. Она принимает единственным аргументом *путь* к исходникам. Т.е. если вы получили сообщение об отсутствии файла, можете *явно* указать исходники таким образом. Как я понял, `use` сохраняет только последнюю указанную директорию, поэтому после каждого использования `use`, при необходимости вернутся к предыдущему исходнику придется *заново* его указать.
**Важно:** путь должен указывать именно к исходникам пакета. Если у вас класс `example.java` из пакета `org.example`, то нужно указать не `{путь к пакету}/org/example/example.java` а просто `{путь к пакету}/`